# What is the meaning of "rather people"?

Tags: meaning

I read a sentence, in Oxford English dictionaries, as an example of the word "vape" which was:
I'd rather people vaped indoors than smoked outside.

What is the meaning of "rather people vaped"?

Comment: **Would rather** is an expression: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/would-rather Specifically, take a closer look at the examples that they have there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe "**I'd rather**..." is short for  "**I had rather...** / "**I would rather...**  "

**had rather** means **to consider or find preferable**

> I **had rather** you left me alone.

I would prefer that you left me alone.

> I **had rather** people vaped indoors than smoked outside.

I would prefer that people vaped indoors…

[Collins, English Dictionary - had rather](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/had-rather)

[Collins, English Dictionary - would rather](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/would-rather)

Comment: would rather or had rather.

Comment: I think *I **had** rather [preferred option]* is [bordering on archaic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&content=I+had+rather+it%2CI+would+rather+it&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20had%20rather%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20would%20rather%20it%3B%2Cc0), compared to *I **would** rather...*